# Алгоритм простого числа

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, простые-числа

Может кто нибудь подсказать, что не так с этим алгоритмом? Проблема в том, что при запуске некоторые числа отображаются в командной строке по несколько раз. В итоге получается, что некоторые числа начала не отображаются и вовсе, если задать number как 200.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int number;
    for (number = 3; number<=20; number++)
    {

        for (int counter = 2; counter*counter<=number; counter++)
        {
            if( number% counter == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            else{
                cout<<number<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы на каждый *не*делитель выводите число...

Вот что вы *хотели*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int number;
    for (number = 3; number<=200; number++)
    {
        bool prime = true;
        for (int counter = 2; counter*counter<=number; counter++)
        {
            if( number% counter == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime) cout << number << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Но учтите, что это далеко не самый эффективный метод...

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под неделителем? Почему при выводе If(prime) в первый цикл он работает? Я извиняюсь если вопрос глупый, но я только начал изучать программирование

Comment: Кажется я понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Значит ли это, что по первому коду он проверяет простое число снова и из-за этого выводит его несколько раз на экран? Тогда второй вопрос. Разве не должен тогда получится бесконечный цикл? Он ведь все равно переходит на проверку другого числа

Comment: Так, я не очень понял ваши вопросы, я опишу свой код. Имеем - внешний цикл от 3 до сколько нужно. Все. Этот цикл безусловно завершается. В пределах этого цикла мы полагаем число a priori простым (флаг `prime`). Проверяем все числа от 2 до корня из числа. Если это делитель - т.е. `number%counter==0`, то 1. меняем значение флага (число точно не простое) и завершаем цикл (командой `break`). Выйдя так или иначе из внутреннего цикла, проверяем, не был ли установлен флаг `prime` равным `false`.

Comment: Не был? Значит, выводим наше простое число и идем на следующую итерацию внешнего цикла. Был? Значит, идем на следующую итерацию, не выводя...